# Geoserver symbols scale differently in different CRS

Tags: gis, geoserver, wms, sld

I am using Geoserver and am getting some odd behaviour with point symbols via WMS.

If I request an image using GetMap in EPSG:27700 I get this image:
[image: Rendering in EPSG:27700]

However, if I do the same request using EPSG:3857. I get this: [image: Rendering in EPSG:3857]

These images are of a layer group to show context, but the SLD code for transformer symbol (interlocking circles) is here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <NamedLayer>
    <Name></Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Transformer</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule> 
          <Title>Transformer</Title>
              <MinScaleDenominator>1</MinScaleDenominator>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>1001</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <PointSymbolizer  uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>wkt://MULTIPOLYGON(((0.75 -0.5, 0.748972 -0.539252, 0.745891 -0.578396, 0.740766 -0.617326, 0.733611 -0.655934, 0.724444 -0.694114, 0.713292 -0.731763, 0.700185 -0.768776, 0.685159 -0.805052, 0.668255 -0.840493, 0.649519 -0.875, 0.629003 -0.908479, 0.606763 -0.940839, 0.582859 -0.97199, 0.557359 -1.001848, 0.53033 -1.03033, 0.501848 -1.057359, 0.47199 -1.082859, 0.440839 -1.106763, 0.408479 -1.129003, 0.375 -1.149519, 0.340493 -1.168255, 0.305052 -1.185159, 0.268776 -1.200185, 0.231763 -1.213292, 0.194114 -1.224444, 0.155934 -1.233611, 0.117326 -1.240766, 0.078396 -1.245891, 0.039252 -1.248972, 0 -1.25, -0.039252 -1.248972, -0.078396 -1.245891, -0.117326 -1.240766, -0.155934 -1.233611, -0.194114 -1.224444, -0.231763 -1.213292, -0.268776 -1.200185, -0.305052 -1.185159, -0.340493 -1.168255, -0.375 -1.149519, -0.408479 -1.129003, -0.440839 -1.106763, -0.47199 -1.082859, -0.501848 -1.057359, -0.53033 -1.03033, -0.557359 -1.001848, -0.582859 -0.97199, -0.606763 -0.940839, -0.629003 -0.908479, -0.649519 -0.875, -0.668255 -0.840493, -0.685159 -0.805052, -0.700185 -0.768776, -0.713292 -0.731763, -0.724444 -0.694114, -0.733611 -0.655934, -0.740766 -0.617326, -0.745891 -0.578396, -0.748972 -0.539252, -0.75 -0.5, -0.748972 -0.460748, -0.745891 -0.421604, -0.740766 -0.382674, -0.733611 -0.344066, -0.724444 -0.305886, -0.713292 -0.268237, -0.700185 -0.231224, -0.685159 -0.194948, -0.668255 -0.159507, -0.649519 -0.125, -0.629003 -0.091521, -0.606763 -0.059161, -0.582859 -0.02801, -0.557359 0.001848, -0.53033 0.03033, -0.501848 0.057359, -0.47199 0.082859, -0.440839 0.106763, -0.408479 0.129003, -0.375 0.149519, -0.340493 0.168255, -0.305052 0.185159, -0.268776 0.200185, -0.231763 0.213292, -0.194114 0.224444, -0.155934 0.233611, -0.117326 0.240766, -0.078396 0.245891, -0.039252 0.248972, 0 0.25, 0.039252 0.248972, 0.078396 0.245891, 0.117326 0.240766, 0.155934 0.233611, 0.194114 0.224444, 0.231763 0.213292, 0.268776 0.200185, 0.305052 0.185159, 0.340493 0.168255, 0.375 0.149519, 0.408479 0.129003, 0.440839 0.106763, 0.47199 0.082859, 0.501848 0.057359, 0.53033 0.03033, 0.557359 0.001848, 0.582859 -0.02801, 0.606763 -0.059161, 0.629003 -0.091521, 0.649519 -0.125, 0.668255 -0.159507, 0.685159 -0.194948, 0.700185 -0.231224, 0.713292 -0.268237, 0.724444 -0.305886, 0.733611 -0.344066, 0.740766 -0.382674, 0.745891 -0.421604, 0.748972 -0.460748, 0.75 -0.5)), ((0.75 0.5, 0.748972 0.460748, 0.745891 0.421604, 0.740766 0.382674, 0.733611 0.344066, 0.724444 0.305886, 0.713292 0.268237, 0.700185 0.231224, 0.685159 0.194948, 0.668255 0.159507, 0.649519 0.125, 0.629003 0.091521, 0.606763 0.059161, 0.582859 0.02801, 0.557359 -0.001848, 0.53033 -0.03033, 0.501848 -0.057359, 0.47199 -0.082859, 0.440839 -0.106763, 0.408479 -0.129003, 0.375 -0.149519, 0.340493 -0.168255, 0.305052 -0.185159, 0.268776 -0.200185, 0.231763 -0.213292, 0.194114 -0.224444, 0.155934 -0.233611, 0.117326 -0.240766, 0.078396 -0.245891, 0.039252 -0.248972, 0 -0.25, -0.039252 -0.248972, -0.078396 -0.245891, -0.117326 -0.240766, -0.155934 -0.233611, -0.194114 -0.224444, -0.231763 -0.213292, -0.268776 -0.200185, -0.305052 -0.185159, -0.340493 -0.168255, -0.375 -0.149519, -0.408479 -0.129003, -0.440839 -0.106763, -0.47199 -0.082859, -0.501848 -0.057359, -0.53033 -0.03033, -0.557359 -0.001848, -0.582859 0.02801, -0.606763 0.059161, -0.629003 0.091521, -0.649519 0.125, -0.668255 0.159507, -0.685159 0.194948, -0.700185 0.231224, -0.713292 0.268237, -0.724444 0.305886, -0.733611 0.344066, -0.740766 0.382674, -0.745891 0.421604, -0.748972 0.460748, -0.75 0.5, -0.748972 0.539252, -0.745891 0.578396, -0.740766 0.617326, -0.733611 0.655934, -0.724444 0.694114, -0.713292 0.731763, -0.700185 0.768776, -0.685159 0.805052, -0.668255 0.840493, -0.649519 0.875, -0.629003 0.908479, -0.606763 0.940839, -0.582859 0.97199, -0.557359 1.001848, -0.53033 1.03033, -0.501848 1.057359, -0.47199 1.082859, -0.440839 1.106763, -0.408479 1.129003, -0.375 1.149519, -0.340493 1.168255, -0.305052 1.185159, -0.268776 1.200185, -0.231763 1.213292, -0.194114 1.224444, -0.155934 1.233611, -0.117326 1.240766, -0.078396 1.245891, -0.039252 1.248972, 0 1.25, 0.039252 1.248972, 0.078396 1.245891, 0.117326 1.240766, 0.155934 1.233611, 0.194114 1.224444, 0.231763 1.213292, 0.268776 1.200185, 0.305052 1.185159, 0.340493 1.168255, 0.375 1.149519, 0.408479 1.129003, 0.440839 1.106763, 0.47199 1.082859, 0.501848 1.057359, 0.53033 1.03033, 0.557359 1.001848, 0.582859 0.97199, 0.606763 0.940839, 0.629003 0.908479, 0.649519 0.875, 0.668255 0.840493, 0.685159 0.805052, 0.700185 0.768776, 0.713292 0.731763, 0.724444 0.694114, 0.733611 0.655934, 0.740766 0.617326, 0.745891 0.578396, 0.748972 0.539252, 0.75 0.5)))</WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="opacity">0</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
                          <Stroke>
            <CssParameter name="stroke">
              <ogc:PropertyName>higher_voltage_colour</ogc:PropertyName>
            </CssParameter>
            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.05</CssParameter>
          </Stroke>
              </Mark>
              <Size>1.25</Size>
                <Rotation>
                  <ogc:Mul>
                      <ogc:PropertyName>orientation</ogc:PropertyName>
                      <ogc:Literal>-1</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:Mul>
            </Rotation>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

It looks like Geoserver isn't scaling the SVG symbol when rendering in EPSG:3857. Has anyone any idea what is going on here and how to fix it?

**Edit**
As another example, below is the SLD for the black line above the orange block which is a unit line scaled to a parameter - this doesn't seem to scale in EPSG:3857 either

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<StyledLayerDescriptor version="1.0.0"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.opengis.net/sld http://schemas.opengis.net/sld/1.0.0/StyledLayerDescriptor.xsd"
  xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/sld" xmlns:ogc="http://www.opengis.net/ogc"
  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">

  <NamedLayer>
    <Name></Name>
    <UserStyle>
      <Title>Low Voltage Board</Title>
      <FeatureTypeStyle>
        <Rule>
          <Title>Low Voltage Board</Title>
          <ogc:Filter>
            <ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
              <ogc:PropertyName>feat_code</ogc:PropertyName>
              <ogc:Literal>lv_board</ogc:Literal>
            </ogc:PropertyIsEqualTo>
          </ogc:Filter>
          <MinScaleDenominator>1</MinScaleDenominator>
          <MaxScaleDenominator>1001</MaxScaleDenominator>
          <PointSymbolizer  uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
            <Graphic>
              <Mark>
                <WellKnownName>
                    wkt://LINESTRING(0 0, 0 1)
                </WellKnownName>
                <Fill>
                  <CssParameter name="opacity">0</CssParameter>
                </Fill>
                          <Stroke>
            <CssParameter name="stroke">
             #000000
            </CssParameter>
            <CssParameter name="stroke-width">0.1</CssParameter>
          </Stroke>
              </Mark>
              <Size>
                 <ogc:PropertyName>board_length</ogc:PropertyName>
                </Size>
                <Rotation>
                  <ogc:Add>
                  <ogc:Mul>
                      <ogc:PropertyName>orientation</ogc:PropertyName>

                      <ogc:Literal>-1</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:Mul>
                    <ogc:Literal>90</ogc:Literal>
                  </ogc:Add>
            </Rotation>
            </Graphic>
          </PointSymbolizer>
        </Rule>

      </FeatureTypeStyle>
    </UserStyle>
  </NamedLayer>
</StyledLayerDescriptor>
```

Comment: can you add the scale for each of those images - it looks like one is zoomed in more than the other. Also 3857 metres are likely to be smaller than 27700 ones.

Comment: The zoom levels are slightly different (I generated the images by hand-coding the URLs to check the issue was actually in the PNG file provided by Geoserver), but I'm more concerned about the relative sizes and positions. In EPSG:27700, the transformer symbol is large enough to touch the squares just above (north) of it, whereas in EPSG:3857, there is a gap.

Answer (score 0):

I've got pretty much the same situation.
Symbols scale fine in EPSG:28992, not in 3857, 4326 en 900913.
In these SRS's the symbols have a height of approximately 2.4 m, instead of 4 meters.
Which is a ratio that is about the same as the km/miles ratio. Coincidence?

In the SLD the UnitsOfMeasure UOM) are set to meters (ground units):

```
<PointSymbolizer uom="http://www.opengeospatial.org/se/units/metre">
  <Graphic>
    <ExternalGraphic>
      <OnlineResource xlink:type="simple" link:href="${veiligh_install_type_id}.svg"/>
        <Format>image/svg</Format>
    </ExternalGraphic>
    <Size>4</Size>
  <Graphic>
<PointSymbolizer>
```